# implicit conversion, override, interoperability

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have the following class in Java:

```
public class GeneralClass {
    public Integer getInt(Double d) {
        return d.intValue();
    }
}
```

I would like to extend this class in scala e.g.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class SpecializedClass extends GeneralClass {

  override def getInt(d: Double): Int = {
    d.intValue()
  }
}
```

The problem is that neither scala.Double nor scala.Int are automatically converted to their respective java types.

**Edit**
The error message is:

> method getInt overrides nothing. Note: the super classes of class
>   SpecializedClass contain the following, non final members named
>   getInt: def getInt(d: Double): Integer

Can anybody explain that and maybe point out an elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getInt` in `SpecializedClass` does not override the method in `GeneralClass`. To be able to override, the function argument in `SpecializedClass` should be contravariant and the return type to be co-variant. Which in your case is not.

So unless you have something in `getInt` in `SpecializedClass` which takes a type `T :> java.lang.Double` and return type as `T <: java.lang.Integer`, it will not override it.

For your question, actually I dont feel the need to have such a method as Scala compiler will implicitly convert Java double to Scala Double.

Comment: I think that your answer is the closest to the one I was looking for. Could you please provide any reference to back it up?

Comment: I had written a small post on covariance and contravariance. http://jatinpuri.com/2012/11/co-variance-contra-variance/ hope it will be useful. For Implicits, http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html is the best reference out there.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
override def getInt(d: Double): Integer = {
   return Integer.valueOf(d.intValue()); // explicit boxing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not really override an existing method (because of different types).

So one possibility is to remove the `override`.

On the other hand, if you really want to have the `override` keyword:

```
override def getInt(d: java.lang.Double): java.lang.Integer = {
  d.intValue()
}
```

Generally speaking, using primitive data types in Java/Scala interoperability can be tricky: Here is another example which deals with primitive data types together with [scala.Option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071061/2390083).